# Tests completes when running in IDEA but fails when running in maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, selenium, testng

I have an application which I'm testing using Selenium WebDriver and TestNG.
I have 15 methods which are marked with @Test annotations.
When i'm starting tests clicking on tests with mouse right button all 15 tests completing successfully, but when I'm starting tests using command-line with "mvn test" Maven output is:

```
  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.company.tests:Selenium:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 43, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Selenium 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Selenium ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\ai\mysel\alexander-aut-webdriver-selenium\fwk\java\trunk\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Selenium ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Selenium ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Selenium ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\ai\mysel\alexander-aut-webdriver-selenium\fwk\java\trunk\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.5:test (default-test) @ Selenium ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\ai\mysel\alexander-aut-webdriver-selenium\fwk\java\trunk\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 21287
Tests run: 22, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 12, Time elapsed: 26.223 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests: 
  openLoginPage(com.company.selenium.tests.LoginTest)
  openRegistrationPage(com.company.selenium.tests.RegistrationTest)

Tests run: 22, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 12
```

openLoginPage() and openRegistration even not marked as @Test, they marked with @BeforeMethod annotation

why there are 22 tests when i running in maven?
how can i fix this so maven will run all 15 tests

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you the following: 
1) take a look at your project POM.xml  : http://gyazo.com/7a9015de5e0f9801848e9ecba62a18e9
and make sure you've got following dependencies in your POM.xml:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>

......

   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


..........
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

2) 2nd step is to  navigate to your project folder (exact one where POM.xml file is located) . 
Open command window and run  there

```
mvn clean test
```

http://gyazo.com/9526e807be8a6fc4ad6211d4aab19b5c

3) also pay attention to   build/plugins section in POM.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Probably the root cause is in   `<version>2.3.2</version>` this one  as far as I can understand from you log provided:

```
ests:Selenium:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 43, column 21
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: still there are more tests than should be, but i somehow recognized that renaming one of my files with tests reduced number of errors. renaming other file with tests didn't help at all. so now i have 19 tests instead of 15, and 1 failure in @ BeforeMethod which is not a test